# discrete version of normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Just what the title says. I want to model probability of number of sales on a given day. I can't use poisson/binomial, because there are indications that the standard deviation of the sales might differ between two products with the same average number of sales.

Is there a discrete version of normal distribution, or something like poisson distribution in which you can independently set the variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For count data like you describe, you probably want a [negative-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).  This is an extension of the Poisson distribution that has an additional parameter that allows for the variance not to be tied to the mean.  This is a distribution that is commonly used for count data, either for straight count data, or in problems where you also have other explanatory variables (where you can use a negative-binomial GLM).  There are some other statistical models that are used for count data, but that is where I would start.  You needn't worry about the connection to the normal distribution here; just look for a distribution that is appropriate to your count data.